# Rewrite undescores to dashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, opencart

I know there's quite a lot of existing questions and answers regarding rewriting underscores to dashes but I can't seem to get it to work for this particular situation.

I am converting an existing web store to Opencart. For some weird reason the old store uses dashes in category names but underscores in products. So existing urls are as follows:

```
www.example.com/category-name/product_name
```

I'd like to rewrite these to:

```
www.example.com/category-name/product-name
```

The .htaccess rules I have so far are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first section to rewrite the underscores and the second to redirect to the index.php. Whilst this works fine to rewrite:

```
www.example.com/category-name/product_name
```

to:

```
www.example.com/category-name/product-name
```

It completely crashes apache out when i enter a url such as:

```
www.example.com/category-name/product_name_with_more_underscores
```

Any help or direction would be gratefully received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.+)$ $1-$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although it no longer crashes on /category-name/product_name_with_more_underscores it also no longer rewrites this. Ideally I need it to rewrite this to /category-name/product-name-with-more-underscores. Many Thanks

Comment: Actually it worked for me. `http://localhost/category-name/product_name_with_more_underscores` got redirected to `http://localhost/category-name/product-name-with-more-underscores` replacing all underscores by hyphen. Make sure this is first rule in your .htaccess and there is no other .htaccess

Comment: Thanks again, actually you're right if I just have the rules you specify it does work. But once I include my rules to redirect to index.php (2nd block in my question) it no longer redirects products_with_multiple_underscores. Is there any way to combine both?

Comment: This works: http://test.local/category-name/product_name. But this http://test.local/category-name/product_name_with_more_underscores now redirects to http://test.local/C:/xampp/htdocs/test.local/category-name/product-name-with-more-underscores

Comment: try updated rule again, you didn't have `RewriteBase`  probably.

Comment: That gave me a server error but removing the / in RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=302,NE] and putting 
RewriteBase / in at the top works. You are the God of .htaccess I kneel before your boundless knowledge.

Comment: You're most welcome. Thanks for compliments, if I am able to solve some interesting problem like this it gives me lot of satisfaction. +1 to your question as well :)

Comment: Thank you... I have got a further issues with it but I've posted it as a new question because it's slightly different to what I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143918/rewrite-single-and-consecutive-underscores-to-dashes